# Application does not appear in taskbar when launched & stays behind main Application

Tags: wpf, mfc

I am launching a WPF application from a MFC Application. Sometimes it happens that when I Launch the WPF Applciation, the applciation does get launched but it does not appear in the taskbar. And stays behind the main application. So I keep waiting that the application has not yet launched. When I minimize the main Application, I see it was already launched. Can anyone please identify whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: you probably need to show us some code. How do you launch your wfp application? do you use CreateProcess?

Comment: `ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), sExePath, NULL, NULL, 0);` this is how Im launching the exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ShellExecute incorrectly. Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The last parameter, nShowCmd, is:

> The flags that specify how an application is to be displayed when it is opened. If lpFile specifies a document file, the flag is simply passed to the associated application. It is up to the application to decide how to handle it. These values are defined in Winuser.h.

Therefore, you need to specify the desired ShowWindow flag. I recommend using either SW_SHOWNORMAL or SW_MAXIMIZE:

```
int nResult = (int)::ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), sExePath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

or

```
int nResult = (int)::ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), sExePath, NULL, NULL, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

It is also a good idea to check the return code of the function. If it succeeds the value in nReturn should be greater than 32.